# Can I use 8x16 tiles on shower walls that measure 39.5" by 35.5" by 39.5"?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I made the mistake of putting 2" x 2" tiles on my shower floor of a tile that is hard to match. This being my first tile job, I didn't plan properly.

Finally, I've found the floor/wall tile from the same series, but it's at a store 1.5 hours from my home in NYC(I'll make the trip if I can use them).

Yet they only have them in tile in sizes of 8x16 and 8x32, and the bullnose tiles, too. Problem is the widths of my shower walls are 39.5" by 35.5" by 39.5". Is there any way I could arrange those tiles on the walls so they would look ok? Or can I cut them into 8x8 tiles and then put them on the walls. The manufacturer says it's a "porcelain tile that looks like marble."

The tile is: Gardenia Orchidea Varenna beige.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: How wide of a grout line are you using? Also - what size are the bullnose tiles?

Comment: The 2x2 floor tiles is about 3/8". I'm not sure what the grout line on the wall should be. The bullnose tiles are 3x16.

Comment: Are you only bull-nosing the top, or the top and two sides?  The bull-nose is the main consideration, especially if the tile has bevelled edges.  You'd typically want to avoid having cut edges where they'll be visible. Do you have or can you get more of the 2" tiles?  That would give more flexibility if you used them to "accent" the larger tiles.

Comment: I can get more of the 2 by 2 tiles! that might give me more flexibility. Hmm...

Comment: ...Just do it all in 2x2 - it will match perfectly, and does not require an absurdly long drive to get.

Comment: With a porcelain tile, all your cut edges need to be in corners or the bottom of the wall.  Having a cut edge facing another till will look bad.  Tiles almost always have some relief (rounding) on the edges, but the cut edge will be sharp and crisp.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to cut them so that the offcuts are not so small - and NOT to try to keep an "uncut edge" anywhere.

So, you'd basically plan to burn 48" of tile on each wall, though you should be able to re-use some of the offcuts around the corner. No getting around the 1.75" ones on the back wall unless you want to get cute and put a 3.5" slice in the middle of two 8x16's to make the width. Whether that looks good to you or not is your call - if it does, consider the same approach on the side walls. Something like:

```
xxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxx
```

and then on the longer sidewalls:

```
xxxxxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx
xxxxxxxx|xxxx|xxxxxxxx
xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx
```

*Look OK* is, of course, a highly variable and personal criteria. In your shoes I'd probably find that I could live with another wall tile, but I'm not you and you're not me.

Comment: I've tried to find a tile that matches, but haven't had any luck. There are too many shades and colors in the tile.  Here is a pic: http://www.tile4you.ru/files/shop/img_small/120454-1.jpg

Comment: So go for contrast, or something like white, black, or black and white that "goes with" anything. That aspect quickly devolves into a "decorating" question that's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Given your dimensions, a herring-bone pattern seems like it would likely get you the least waste using 8*16 tiles (obviously laid out with cleaner lines than the mock-up below):

[image]

Comment: Will I be able to cut the tile with a wet saw so the cut edge will look good?

Comment: @joe979xx - It depends on the tile - for most tiles other than stone I'd say probably not.  You'd typically want to hide your cuts in a corner or under some sort of trim.